# Import warning PACKAGE.egg is added to sys.path

Tags: python, setuptools

I try to install my own python package. Now I get this error:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/__init__.py:3: UserWarning: Module twisted was already imported from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/__init__.pyc, but /root/PACKAGE-0.1-rc is being added to sys.path
  import pkg_resources
```

Weard, cause I did no where told him to add this path to sys.path.
After deleting this folder I get the same error but with a different path

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/__init__.py:3: UserWarning: Module twisted was already imported from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/__init__.pyc, but /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PACKAGE-0.1_rc-py2.7.egg is being added to sys.path
  import pkg_resources
```

I googled for it and found also a smiliar error for this here: [Debian bug report for pkg_resources](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=473584)
Someone there reproduces this error:

```
$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Apr 20 2011, 09:34:38) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pkg_resources
__main__:1: UserWarning: Module paste was already imported from None, but /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages is being added to sys.path
```

But I can't reproduce it on this way.

This error looks also like this [Stackoverflow - Module pytz was already imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239518/module-pytz-was-already-imported).
But I can't get any usefull informations for me from this post.

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PACKAGE-0.1_rc-py2.7.egg
```

That is for me a folder where my package lives in.

I'm using python-setuptools 0.6.24-1.
On setuptools bug tracker it says that this error should be fixed in version 0.6c10 [Setuptools Bugfix](http://bugs.python.org/setuptools/issue36)

Has someone an advice for me to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this by upgrading setuptools to 2.0.2 using:

```
sudo pip install -U setuptools
```

Comment: I was having a similar problem and this solved my issue, thanks!