# virtualenv warnings: "same location as system..."

Tags: python, virtualenv

I get the following warnings when I try to import distutils or use mercurial or a variety of other python codes:

```
$ ~/virtual-python/bin/python -c "import distutils; print distutils.__file__"
/Users/adam/virtual-python/lib/python2.7/distutils/__init__.py:13: UserWarning: The virtualenv distutils package at %s appears to be in the same location as the system distutils?
  "The virtualenv distutils package at %s appears to be in the same location as the system distutils?")
/Users/adam/virtual-python/lib/python2.7/distutils/__init__.pyc
```

What does this mean?  I hope the system distutils is not in my virtualenv directory, but that *seems* to be what the warning is saying.

<s>The system</s> A user-installed python is included in my `sys.path`:
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7` (and subdirectories)
which I suspect is the cause of the problem, but I'm not sure.

The warnings don't prevent anything from working, but I'd rather have a real solution than call python with a -W flag each time (["putting electrical tape over the warning light"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4595844/814354))

Comment: `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/` is the location of the OS X system Python; `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` is the location of a user-installed Python, possibly from a python.org installer or a third-party.  If you are using it, did you install its own copy of easy_install (via Distribute or setuptools) before you installed virtualenv?

Comment: Almost certainly yes; `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/` exists.

Comment: No, distutils is part of the Python standard library and is included with every standard Python installation.  `easy_install` (Distribute or setuptools) is a third-party package, not part of the standard library; it uses distutils.  Apple ships instances of `easy_install` for each of the system Python versions.  If you install additional versions, you need to install Distribute or setuptools for each of them as well.

Comment: Yes, distribute is installed.

Comment: @keflavich, did you ever find a real answer to this problem?

Comment: No, but I've since switched to anaconda and I haven't seen the warning since

Answer (score 0):

This is a dumb answer, and the wrong approach, but I was getting this error:

`/Users/adam/virtual-python/lib/python2.7/distutils/__init__.py:13: UserWarning: The virtualenv distutils package at %s appears to be in the same location as the system distutils?
  "The virtualenv distutils package at %s appears to be in the same location as the system distutils?")`

So I just removed line 13 from that file.  Stupid, but effective.  Warning light removed.  I'd prefer to accept a real answer, though.

Comment: Stupid dumb solution is fine for a stupid/dumb error message :)