# Favoring a pip-installed module over the standard library copy

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse, pypi

I've been digging into a `Module was already imported` warning I get when I run `ipython` and various other programs in Python 2.7:

```
$ ipython
[path to python]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/path.py:122:
UserWarning: Module argparse was already imported from [path to python]/lib/python2.7/argparse.pyc, but 
[path to python]/lib/python2.7/site-packages is being added to sys.path
  import pkg_resources
```

This stems from `argparse` being included both in the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) and as a [module from PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse).

In my case, the [stevedore](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stevedore) package [required](https://github.com/openstack/stevedore/blob/40aeacd721ffa515aecf9cc0f07c59ad35d79fcb/requirements.txt) the `argparse` module be installed. There's [unsettled discussion](https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-stevedore?field.searchtext=argparse) on stevedore's development site about [constraining](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0496/) this requirement to Python 2.6 (which didn't have `argparse` built-in), but stevedore is just an example: many packages require `argparse`, and some even require a version higher than what's bundled in the standard library. (For example, [`remotecv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/remotecv) requires [`argparse>=1.2.1,<1.3.0`](https://github.com/thumbor/remotecv/blob/75badd731d16cef7511971150c76b4285d4386c8/requirements.txt), as of this writing.)

What's the most Pythonic way to deal with this warning, assuming you do want to keep using the third-party package?

- [Suppress the warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4595844/134610)?
- Uninstall the `argparse` module in defiance of requirements?
- Excise `argparse` from your standard library?
- Something else?

There are similar questions at “[How do you correct Module already loaded UserWarnings in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861336/how-do-you-correct-module-already-loaded-userwarnings-in-python)” and “[Module pytz was already imported.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239518/module-pytz-was-already-imported/7239620#7239620)” I'll let the wise crowds decide if this is a duplicate, but I don't believe it is. Those were both asked 4+ years ago, the package distribution tools have changed (this isn't about [`distribute`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) or `.egg`s), and though the warning is the same, I don't think they were caused by this overlapping stdlib/PyPI issue.

Heads up to anyone researching this:  `pip list` may [exclude](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1570) `argparse` from its results ([somewhat controversially](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1610)).

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with the previously installed `argparse` versions, but may be able to make few helpful observations.

`ipython` is a heavy user of `argparse`, though in its own way.  It builds a parser from the `config` files, and uses that to process your commandline.  So your commandline has a last minute chance to override many comfig options.

And `%magic` commands are parsed with a version of `argparse`.

Development of the PyPi version ceased once it became standard (Python 2.7).  Version number in the standard is meaningless.  It is still (in the latest Python 3.5).

```
In [4]: argparse.__version__
Out[4]: '1.1'
```

I don't know how it can be done, but any module that seeks to install `argparse` should first check the Python version.  If it 2.7 or newer, it should use the standard `argparse`.

Keep in mind that the argparse module is one self contained file, `argparse.py`. In my experience `ipython` works fine with a copy of that file in my own current working directory.  I do that all the time when testing patches for argparse bug/issues.

Other than 2.6 compatibility, I can't think of a reason why a package would want a PyPi version of argparse instead of the standard one.  Does any of the discussions indicate what kinds of incompatibilities might arise?

According the current PyPi version (1.4) `NEWS.txt`, the repository is now

https://github.com/ThomasWaldmann/argparse

It may be work exploring there to see what compatibility issues there are between than and the standard version(s).

Both the PyPi version and the standard library have `test_argparse.py` unittest files.  They could be used to test for compatibilities.

Comment: It sounds like you favor “Uninstall the argparse module in defiance of requirements?” In stevedore's case, the rationale was to include it because some modules “[introspect dependencies](https://review.openstack.org/#/c/197660/).” I'll admit that though I meant this to be a general question, I've checked a few other modules and haven't seen the issue discussed.