# Pip dosen't show the installed module - argparse

Tags: python, pip, argparse

I've already installed argparse successfully, but it doesn't show up on pip list.

```
C:\Python34>pip install argparse
Collecting argparse
  Downloading argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: argparse
Successfully installed argparse-1.4.0

C:\Python34>pip install argparse
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): argparse in c:\python34\lib\site-packages    
C:\Python34>pip list
Bottleneck (1.0.0)
chardet (2.3.0)
fuzzywuzzy (0.10.0)
nltk (3.1)
numexpr (2.6.0)
numpy (1.10.4)
pandas (0.18.1)
pip (8.1.2)
python-dateutil (2.5.3)
pytz (2016.4)
scipy (0.17.0)
setuptools (18.2)
six (1.10.0)
```

on Windows 10.

Comment: I know this might be too obvious, but have you checked in the c:\python34\lib\site-packages directory to see if argparse exists?

Comment: Why are you trying to add `argparse` to Python3.4?  It comes standard with that version.  From Waldmann's docs: `The PyPi argparse package is mostly for people who want to have argparse on
older Pythons, like < 2.7 or < 3.2 because it was not in stdlib back then.`

Comment: @hpaulj I'm trying to install a package, and it fails, saying "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setup.py". and I found the argparse was not in the list, so I suspected it cause the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Its Not importnat.
You Can Check Your Library With **show**.

```
pip show argparse
```

Result:

```
C:\Users\ALiRezaCH>pip show argparse
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: argparse
Version: 1.4.0
Summary: Python command-line parsing library
Home-page: https://github.com/ThomasWaldmann/argparse/
Author: Thomas Waldmann
Author-email: tw@waldmann-edv.de
Installer: pip
License: Python Software Foundation License
Location: c:\users\alirezach\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Classifiers:
  Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable
  Environment :: Console
  Intended Audience :: Developers
  License :: OSI Approved :: Python Software Foundation License
  Operating System :: OS Independent
  Programming Language :: Python
  Programming Language :: Python :: 2
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3
  Programming Language :: Python :: 2.3
  Programming Language :: Python :: 2.4
  Programming Language :: Python :: 2.5
  Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6
  Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3.0
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3.1
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3.2
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4
  Topic :: Software Development
```

Answer (score 0):

Search tags for the package that is expecting `argparse`.  I recall an earlier SO question about a specific package expecting a specific `argparse` version.

In the standard version, `argparse.__version__` is `1.1`.  That is, the version number hasn't changed since it was added to Python.  But that @Waldman version is up to 1.4.0, even though, there's no development there.  I haven't studied that version to see how it differs from the version currently shipped with Python.  Differences, if any, should be minor.

I don't know how you can resolve the install issues.  If you get around that, and you still have issues using the standard `argparse`, come back with your questions.

[Favoring a pip-installed module over the standard library copy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34360077/901925) - found with '[argparse] pypi'.